# Spinner not displayed

Tags: android, spinner

This is the function ,I am trying to use the spinner , data getting from the API but the issue is that the spinner drop down not display.I am new to android.I attached the code below.Please suggest me solution. There is no any error in the code.I print the array i get the data.Only problem is that the drop down not display. When i click on the button response getting.

```
        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    String access=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"ticket","update_properties","");
                    JSONArray access_denied = null;
                    try 
                    {
                        access_denied = new editProperties(access).execute().get();

                    String access_result =access_denied.toString();
                    if(access_result.equals("[\"Accessdenied\"]"))
                    {
                        Operation.showToast(getApplicationContext(), R.string.access);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Log.d("In the else Condition : ","Success");      
                        String DEPT_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"ticket","get_department","&vis_all_department=1");

                        final String dept=tv_dept.getText().toString();
                        filter_dept_id=tv_dept_id.getText().toString(); 

                        if(v.getId()==R.id.td_tv_dept)
                        {       
                            ArrayAdapter<String> dept_Adapter=op.get_dept_adapter(DEPT_URL,DEPARTMENT,Ticket_properties.this,domain_id);

                            final ArrayAdapter<String> dept_id_Adapter=op.get_dept_adapter(DEPT_URL,DEPARTMENT_ID,Ticket_properties.this,domain_id);

                            spin.setAdapter(dept_Adapter);

                            final int dept_Position = dept_Adapter.getPosition(dept);



                            spin.setSelection(dept_Position);//THIS ONE
                            spin.performClick();        

                            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int pos, long id) {   
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String selected_item=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                                    String selected_item_id=dept_id_Adapter.getItem(pos).toString();

                                    String filter="&vis_ticket_id="+Ticket_id+"&vis_action=department&vis_update_id="+selected_item_id;
                                    String UPDATE_DEPT_URL=op.getUrl(getApplicationContext(),"ticket","update_properties",filter);

                                    JSONArray dept_array;
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        dept_array = new editProperties(UPDATE_DEPT_URL).execute().get();
                                        String result =dept_array.toString();                       

                                        if(result.equals("[\"success\"]"))
                                        {       
                                            tv_dept.setText(selected_item);
                                            tv_dept_id.setText(selected_item_id);           
                                        }
                                        else {Operation.showToast(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error);}
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();


                                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();

                                    }
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                                    spin.setSelection(dept_Position);

                                }
                            });     
                        }
                        else if
                        {
                            //NEXT CODE
                        }
```

//**********************************************************************

```
            public ArrayAdapter<String> get_dept_adapter(String URL, String ITEM, Activity context,String domain_id) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                    JSONArray array ;
                    List<String> item_list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    try {
                        array=new adapter(URL+"&vis_encode=json",context).execute().get();

                        for (int i = 0; i <array.length(); i++) 
                        {           
                            JSONObject object;
                            try {
                                object = array.getJSONObject(i);            
                                String new_domain_id=object.getString("domain_id");
                                if(domain_id.equals(new_domain_id))
                                {
                                    String item=object.getString(ITEM);
                                    item_list.add(item);    
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> item_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,item_list);
                    item_Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                    return item_Adapter;
                }
```

//***********************************************************

```
            Hello i just added the android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"  these two lines and working fine.

            Previous
            ==========
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/td_spin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

            After
            =======
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/td_spin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown"
            />
```

Comment: why are you calling `spin.performClick(); `

Comment: @kamran : Its previous code I just solve the bug.But when i comment spin.performClick()............ the output not getting.

Comment: great.. update your question with solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this code...

XML file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
      android:text="Category:"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

   <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java file

```
// Spinner element
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  // Spinner Drop down List (in your case set data from api)
  List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
  categories.add("Item 1");
  categories.add("Item 2");
  categories.add("Item 3");
  categories.add("Item 4");

  // Creating adapter for spinner
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

  // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  // attaching data adapter to spinner
  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you parag its working for demo.I just change the android:spinnerMode="dropdown" to dialog and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your layout

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/select_model"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

creat spinner_border.xml in your drawable folder

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

setup spinner like this in your activity.java

```
private void setUpSpinner(ArrayList<String> mModels){
     modelSpinnerAdapter = new SelectionListAdapter(this, mModels);
    dropdown.setAdapter(modelSpinnerAdapter);
    dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           // model = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


}
```

and this is SelectionListAdapter.java

```
public class SelectionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> listItemTitles;
public SelectionListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listItemTitles) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listItemTitles = listItemTitles;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItemTitles.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listItemTitles.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_row_item, parent, false);
    }
    TextView listItemTitleView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selector_item_texiView);
    listItemTitleView.setText(listItemTitles.get(position).toUpperCase());
    return convertView;
}
```

}

select_row_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android = 
 "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="35dp">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:id="@+id/selector_item_texiView" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks hasan for help.